# Time range slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, backbone.js

In above link, time range slider is perfectly working with older version of jquery, but it does not support new version of jquery. Any solution for that? And also any new plugin for select time slot using range slider in jquery.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/ghusse/LJrYf/1/][1]
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: There is no link above... BTW if a plugin doesn't work with a new version of dependency, best way is to contact it's owner... Generally he needs to patch the plugin according to migration guidelines. It's probably won't be easy to patch such things externally...

Answer (score 0):

It is not problem with a version of jQuery you're using. The problem is that you need to include jQuery UI script in your app.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In your code example you checked jQuery UI, so because that it will work.
Include jQuery UI on the top of the scripts and now it will work.
From : http://jqueryui.com/download/ :

- 1.12.1(Stable, for jQuery1.7+)
- 1.11.4(Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)
- 1.10.4(Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)
- 1.9.2(Legacy, for jQuery1.6+)

See example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJrYf/173/)

Comment: No, it doesn't work with latest version of jQuery even with jQuery UI. Even if it did, it'll only work for jQuery versions supported by the version of jQuery UI. I'm pretty sure it won't work for *any* version of jQuery.

Comment: See this... http://jsfiddle.net/LJrYf/174/ (The plugin probably doesn't support version 3.x)

Comment: yes it doesn't work in latest version of jQuery. I have tried lots of time but didn't get any solution for this.